# how to sort an array in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I have an array like this:

```
[Object { id=1027355606, name="Canada Post", 
job_assignments=[Object { id=1027355607,    user_id=976369075, sequence=-1}]}, 
Object { id=1027355607, name="Ottawa Marriott Hotel", 
job_assignments=[Object { id=1027355606, user_id=976369075, sequence=1}]}]
```

and I want to sort the array by the sequence number (from smallest to biggest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a CoffeeScript question, it's a JavaScript question. CoffeeScript doesn't add any new sorting functionality. You want [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

The CoffeeScript syntax would be

```
myArray.sort (a, b) ->
  a.job_assignments.sequence - b.job_assignments.sequence
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but one more question, can I use a.job_assignments[0].sequence instead of a.job_assignments.sequence? Since job_assignments is also an array